# How to build a generic function for all my models

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel 8.

I want to imagine a generic function which can be called from several models.

This function allows to create an uuid + retrieve the connected user.

The function is (for the moment) in one of my models. Example :

```
class Organization extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * Generate an uuid for the key.
     */
    public static function boot(): void
    {
        parent::boot();
        self::creating(function ($model): void {
            $model->id = Uuid::uuid4()->toString();
            if (Auth::check()) {
                $model->created_by = Auth::user()->id;
            }
        });

        self::updating(function ($model): void {
            $model->updated_by = Auth::user()->id;
        });
    }

    .....
}
```

This function works fine !
But of course I cannot go on like that on all my models, I am generating a lot of duplicated code.

How to do such generic function ?

Thanks for your suggestions (it's certainly more a PHP question than a lavarel question).

Comment: You either create an Interface (Contract in Laravel) or define a trait and use this trait in every Model.

Comment: You can use traits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
namespace App\Traits;

use Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid;

trait HasUuid
{
    /**
     * Get the route key for the model.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'uuid'; // in case you are using uuid instead of ID
    }

    /**
     * The "booting" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function bootHasUuid()
    {
        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->id = Uuid::uuid4()->toString();
            if (Auth::check()) {
                $model->created_by = Auth::user()->id;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Your Model**

```
use App\Traits\HasUuid;

class Organization extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, hasUuid;
}
```

and the same for updating you can use another trait .. and do the same

Comment: I cannot find the documentation about that. If I have understood, the function name inside the trait must be like bootXXXXX. Correct ?

Comment: Yes name it as the Trait name, also you can add additional methods if you want to, you can search for how to use traits with Laravel... (you have already seen HasFactory trait you can see that example too)